# undefined method `email' for #<UserInfo:0xc0ac77c>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this problem in rails..
It says `undefined method email for #<UserInfo:0xc0ac77c>`
I debug this several times i could not trace the error.

here is the sample code i have.

***user_infos_controller.erb***

```
class UserInfosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_user_profile, only: :index

  def index
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    puts @user
  end

  def new
    @user_info = current_user.build_user_info

  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(current_user)
  end

  def create

    @user_info = UserInfo.create(
      user_id: current_user.id,
      fname: params[:user_info][:fname],
      lname: params[:user_info][:lname],
      bday: params[:user_info][:bday],
      address: params[:user_info][:address],
      picture: params[:user_info][:picture])


    #if @user_info.save
      #redirect_to user_infos
    #else
      #render new_user_info_path
    #end
  end

  private
  def profile_params
    params.require(:user_info).permit(:fname, :lname, :bday, :address, :picture)
  end

  private

   def check_user_profile
    user = User.find(current_user)

    if !user.user_info
      redirect_to new_user_info_path
    end

  end
end
```

***new.html.erb***

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_info, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
        <% if @user_info.errors.any? %>
           <h2><%= pluralize(@user_info.errors.count, "error") %> Prevented this User from saving </h2>
            <ul>
            <% @user_info.errors.full_messages.each do |mg| %>
             <li><%= msg %></li>
             <% end %>
             </ul>
         <% end %>

          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :picture, input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :fname, input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :lname, input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :address, input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.date_field :bday, input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Save</button>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

This is for the user database

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

And this is for user_infos database

```
class CreateUserInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_infos do |t|
      t.string :fname
      t.string :lname
      t.date :bday
      t.string :address

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end



class AddAttachmentPictureToUserInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :user_infos do |t|
      t.attachment :picture
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :user_infos, :picture
  end
end
```

***rails console***

```
    Started POST "/user_infos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-16 13:44:14 +0800
Processing by UserInfosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ig6pSrP9EV7ivQ3DRG/XPcwSQmr8oRhX+4YUtuxxqn/71ViwodxX06IMaQrzEQOWvOEjohAB1suFhubz0+cAJw==", "user_info"=>{"fname"=>"das", "lname"=>"dasa", "address"=>"dsasd", "bday"=>"2015-06-16"}}
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (2.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 148ms (ActiveRecord: 14.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for #<UserInfo:0xbcaa624>):
  app/controllers/user_infos_controller.rb:19:in `create'


  Rendered /home/allanprog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (20.2ms)
  Rendered /home/allanprog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (11.9ms)
  Rendered /home/allanprog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered /home/allanprog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (108.5ms)
Cannot render console with content type multipart/form-dataAllowed content types: [#<Mime::Type:0xa39d5f0 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, #<Mime::Type:0xa39d474 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:text, @string="text/plain">, #<Mime::Type:0xa38b65c @synonyms=[], @symbol=:url_encoded_form, @string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">]
```

***user model***

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :pins
  has_one :user_info

end
```

***user_info model***

```
class UserInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :picture, styles: { medium: "300x300>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

Comment: Please post the complete error log.

Comment: Where it's throwing undefined method email for #<UserInfo:0xc0ac77c>?

Comment: please add more context like your exact code or error logs. and what is `picture` in `new.html.erb` form. Not able to find any migration for `picture` in `user_infos`.

Comment: added some information :)

Comment: This could be related to Devise. Need some expert here.

Comment: I think this error come from your views.  Did you wrote something like userinfo.email in your template? Show your views.

Answer (score 1):

Devise method in your models accepts some options to configure its modules.

So if you use devise on User model then you have to remove Devise methods from UserInfo model which is below

Remove this from UserInfo

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

For configuring Devise for multiple models have look at following documentation link
  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for getting `NoMethodError (undefined method 'email' for #<UserInfo:0xbcaa624>)` error, but 1 issue I can see is :

In `create` method of `UserInfosController` you have written :

```
@user_info = UserInfo.create(
  user_id: current_user.id,
  fname: params[:user_info][:fname],
  lname: params[:user_info][:lname],
  bday: params[:user_info][:bday],
  address: params[:user_info][:address],
  picture: params[:user_info][:picture])
```

but in `user_infos` table you haven't added the column for `user_id`. You should add the column `user_id` to `user_infos` table through migration like this :

```
class AddUserIdToUserInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :user_infos do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true, index:true
    end
  end

  def self.down
    t.remove_references(:user)
  end
end
```